# How to stop my discord bot on herokuapp.com

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have my Discord bot deployed to heroku. I can stop it by turning off [this thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnXpd.png) ([the full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtAFs.png)). How can I do the same thing through the command line (win10)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command which makes use of [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) assuming that you have it configured for your app.

```sh
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw the same solution, but didn’t realise to change ‘web’ to ‘worker’ Xd